# Taxonomy manage fields wrong field edit url

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities

I have updated my project to the latest updates available using drush and suddenly found no field names and wrong field form url in

```
 admin/structure/taxonomy/%taxonomy_name/fields
```

As in the picture, have that issue happened before and how to fix

[image]

**Edit:** I coudn't also be able to add new fields and fatal error occurs

```
FieldException: Attempt to update an instance of a nonexistent field . in field_update_instance() (line 557 of /modules/field/field.crud.inc
```

despite being able to add/edit/delete terms

manage display return error

```
Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /modules/field_ui/field_ui.admin.inc on line 1025
```

The issue is reported in [issue nr 1275900](https://www.drupal.org/node/1275900).

It only happened with taxonomy and other entities work fine.

Comment: Have you run update.php?

Comment: Yes I did, reverted back to another installation and still the same

Comment: Perhaps roll back to your previous version (restore backup) and check that you have not defined any aliases for taxonomies before upgrading? admin/config/search/path

Comment: the path module is not enabled, I have been reverted back to a previous DB and deployed changes via features but still don't see fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem solved by simply patching the field module file-> field.module function named  **field_extract_bundle**

```
function field_extract_bundle($entity_type, $bundle) {
  if (is_string($bundle)) {
    return $bundle;
  }

$info = entity_get_info($entity_type);
if (is_object($bundle) && isset($info['bundle keys']['bundle']) &&     isset($bundle->{$info['bundle keys']['bundle']})) {
return $bundle->{$info['bundle keys']['bundle']};
}
//ADDED THAT ELSE
else{
  return $bundle->machine_name;
 }
}
```

the function tries to return the machine name of the entity as appeared above.

By doing some debugging I realized that the the object sent in the calling function **field_ui_field_overview_form** file->field_ui.admin.inc is n't the same as sent in drupal script before our continuous development in that project.

We added many other modules and edit configuration but the most related that **I think caused that issue is features exporting the taxonomy vocabulary** as the bundle object is the same exported in features so it may be some missing or conflict happened when deploying vocabularies with features

Please contribute your ideas!

Comment: Patching the core is a no go.

Comment: You are right but we didn't come to another solution yet

Comment: Please check if your all other modules are up to date, especially those adding new keys to field definitions like field translations. (https://www.drupal.org/node/1275900#comment-7193756)

Comment: All modules are up to date and the core also is up to date

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, and the cause turned out to be a bug in the Commerce Services module. There is a working patch for this in the module issue queue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2024813#comment-7718289

Answer (score -1):

Re-install website if possible.

You can find the solution for `field_ui.admin.inc` here: [Manage Custom Display: Unsupported operand types in field_ui/field_ui.admin.inc](https://www.drupal.org/node/1261248#comment-7929377)

> Edit field_ui.admin.inc line 1026:

```
$settings += field_info_formatter_settings($formatter_type);
```

> to

```
$settings .= field_info_formatter_settings($formatter_type);
```

> Open the error page, save it and then change back the code.

Comment: I did that patch but it only solves the error with manage display link only, my answer solves the error with both manage fields and manage display. I see its an issue with features module export vocabulary.